# Implicit conversion from enum type 'NSTextAlignment' aka 'enum NSTextAlignment' to diff. enumeration type 'UITextAlignment' aka 'enum UITextAlignment'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and getting the following warning when trying to compile my objective C code:

```
**Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'NSTextAlignment' (aka 'enum NSTextAlignment') to different enumeration type 'UITextAlignment' (aka 'enum UITextAlignment')**
```

The Warning is in `abcLabel.m`:

```
_**CTTextAlignment alignment = CTTextAlignmentFromUITextAlignment(label.textAlignment);**_
```

Any help to fix this Warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6+ `UILabel`'s `textAlignment` property is of type `NSTextAlignment` (prior to that it was of type `UITextAlignment`). If you're compiling for iOS 6 or greater, simply switch to use `NSTextAlignmentToCTTextAlignment()` instead.

Comment: thanks but another warning occur :  Implicit declaration of function 'CTTextAlignmentFromNSTextAlignment' is invalid in C99.. Any Help??

Comment: Apologies, I got the API the wrong way round. The function is actually NSTextAlignmentToCTTextAlignment(). I've edited my answer to make it correct.

Comment: But what I write instead of CTLineBreakModeFromUILineBreakMode?

Comment: I don't think there's a library function for that, but I'd suggest writing one! Maybe call it `NSLineBreakModeToCTLineBreakMode(NSLineBreakMode nsLineBreakMode)`. Looking at the two enums, all the function need do is return the input `nsLineBreakMode` cast as a `CTLineBreakMode`.